# AWS EC2 metadata for security credentials gives empty response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created an ec2 and assigned ec2 full access role in the launch step. The following image shows the confirmation output in the ec2 console.

[image]

When I try to retrive the aws security credentails via the metadata im getting an empty response.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials
```

But when I try to invoke the info it provides the below response.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2018-08-20T07:03:12Z",
  "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::accountID:instance-profile/ec2-full-access-role",
  "InstanceProfileId" : "Instance profile ID"
}
```

Have any one else also came across the same issue, or is there any workaround to get the security credentials ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the slash at the end:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

It will then return the name of the role.

Thus, for a role of `ec2-full-access-role` you would use:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ec2-full-access-role/
```